# Reverse engineering TPMS sensor data

Tags: binary-analysis, decryption, encodings, protocol

I'm trying to reverse engineer data received from TPMS (car tyre pressure) sensors. I used `rtl_433` tool to capture the data from sensor at 433 MHz. Tool was able to detect data is using FSK modulation and Manchester encoding.

Using `reveng` I confirmed that end of data consists of 8 bit CRC. At the beginning is 32-bit sensor id, then there should be tyre pressure, temperature data and at least few status bits (together 5 bytes of unknown data). I'm not sure if these data are 8/10/16 bits each, nor their endianess or int/float. I have made a simple PHP script to try several combinations, but didn't get meaningful values with any of them.

The sensor IDs are: `1c/1d/1e/1f e0 ed a5`.

Output from `reveng -a 4 -w 8 -s`:

```
width=8  poly=0x07  init=0xd3  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x00  check=0xd4  name=(none)
```

Tyre pressures as shown on car display were from 211 kPa in the beginning to 220 kPa at the end after few minutes of driving. Outside temperature was about 5 degC, so final tyre temp could be maybe 15-20 degC at the end, so the question is how to decode the data get these values?

Here is data from 4 sensors:

```
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d5 66 c7 f1 10 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d4 66 c7 f1 06 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 44 d6 66 c7 e4 0a 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 44 d4 66 c7 e4 26 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 55 d4 68 c8 da 23 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d5 66 c7 db bf 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 41 d6 65 c8 cb 2d 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 41 d5 65 c8 cb 17 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d5 68 c8 f7 8f 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d4 68 c8 f7 99 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 44 d6 66 c7 f7 81 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 41 d5 64 c8 eb 17 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 55 d5 68 c8 da c7 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d5 65 c7 c8 f0 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d4 65 c7 c8 e6 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d5 65 c8 d9 76 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d4 64 c8 d3 d0 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 55 d6 67 c8 df d8 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 55 d5 67 c8 df e2 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 55 d4 67 c8 df f4 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d6 65 c7 ef 46 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d5 65 c7 ef 7c 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d4 65 c7 ef 6a 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 44 d6 65 c7 f3 d2 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 44 d4 65 c7 f3 fe 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d5 64 c8 f6 b6 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d4 64 c8 f6 a0 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d6 65 c7 f9 af 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d4 65 c7 f9 83 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d6 64 c7 f7 97 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d5 64 c7 f7 ad 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d4 64 c7 f7 bb 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 55 d6 67 c8 f5 85 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 55 d5 67 c8 f5 bf 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d5 64 c7 f3 3a 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d4 64 c7 f3 2c 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d6 64 c7 f4 d5 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d5 64 c7 f4 ef 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d4 64 c7 f4 f9 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 41 d4 64 c8 f6 d9 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d6 67 c8 f7 f2 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d5 64 c7 f3 43 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 44 d6 64 c7 f4 5e 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 44 d5 64 c7 f4 64 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 55 d6 68 c8 f5 30 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 55 d5 68 c8 f5 0a 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 55 d4 68 c8 f5 1c 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d5 65 c7 f4 b6 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d6 65 c7 f5 4b 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d4 65 c7 f5 67 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d6 64 c8 f2 1b 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d5 64 c8 f2 21 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d4 64 c8 f2 37 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 55 d6 67 c8 ed 46 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 55 d5 67 c8 ed 7c 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d5 64 c7 f3 b1 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d4 64 c7 f3 a7 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 44 d6 64 c7 f3 b9 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 44 d5 64 c7 f3 83 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 44 d4 64 c7 f3 95 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d5 64 c8 ed f7 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d4 64 c8 ed e1 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 55 d4 67 c8 ea f4 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d6 64 c7 dc cd 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d4 64 c7 dc e1 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d6 64 c7 da 1f 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d5 64 c7 da 25 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d4 64 c7 da 33 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 41 d4 64 c7 f4 14 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d6 67 c8 f2 e9 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d5 67 c8 f2 d3 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d6 63 c7 c3 ff 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d5 63 c7 c3 c5 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d4 63 c7 c3 d3 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 41 d6 63 c7 dd 7a 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 41 d4 63 c7 dd 56 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 55 d6 67 c8 e0 1c 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 55 d5 67 c8 e0 26 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d6 64 c6 d6 1c 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d6 63 c7 d9 f2 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d4 63 c7 d9 de 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d6 63 c8 d4 ff 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d5 63 c8 d4 c5 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 55 d4 67 c8 d6 cb 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 44 d6 64 c7 d3 59 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d5 64 c6 d4 51 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d6 63 c7 e9 04 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d4 63 c7 e9 28 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 55 d6 67 c8 eb df 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 55 d4 67 c8 eb f3 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d6 63 c7 9d db 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d5 63 c7 9d e1 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d4 63 c6 9a 37 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 41 d6 63 c7 d6 c0 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 41 d5 63 c7 d6 fa 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d6 66 c8 cf 31 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d5 66 c8 cf 0b 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 44 d6 62 c7 f4 23 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 44 d5 62 c7 f4 19 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d6 63 c6 f5 68 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d5 63 c6 f5 52 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d4 63 c6 f5 44 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 41 d6 63 c7 df 74 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 55 d4 66 c8 f7 47 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d5 63 c7 f5 e1 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d6 64 c6 e4 42 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d6 5f c6 d4 1f 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d5 5f c6 d4 25 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d4 5f c6 d4 33 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 55 d6 67 c8 eb df 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d6 61 c7 dd 5e 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d5 61 c7 dd 64 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d4 61 c7 dd 72 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d4 62 c6 f2 c8 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d6 66 c8 e4 e0 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d5 66 c8 e4 da 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d4 66 c8 e4 cc 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 41 d4 62 c7 e2 0b 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d6 63 c6 f5 d1 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d4 63 c6 f5 fd 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d6 60 c6 e4 db 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d5 60 c6 e4 e1 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d4 60 c6 e4 f7 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 41 d6 62 c6 f4 db 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 41 d5 62 c6 f4 e1 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 41 d4 62 c6 f4 f7 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 44 d5 63 c6 f3 72 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 44 d4 63 c6 f3 64 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d6 61 c5 ef c7 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d5 62 c6 c6 eb 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d5 61 c5 dd e8 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d4 61 c5 dd fe 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d6 62 c7 f1 27 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d5 62 c7 f1 1d 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d4 62 c7 f1 0b 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 44 d6 62 c5 d6 15 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 44 d4 62 c5 d6 39 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d5 61 c5 9f 58 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d4 61 c5 9f 4e 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 55 d5 65 c7 85 76 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 41 d6 62 c6 ca ea 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 41 d4 62 c6 ca c6 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d5 61 c6 f3 2f 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d6 60 c5 f0 88 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d5 60 c5 f0 b2 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d4 60 c5 f0 a4 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 55 d5 65 c7 e8 f9 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 41 d6 61 c6 ec 2e 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 41 d5 61 c6 ec 14 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 41 d4 61 c6 ec 02 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 44 d5 62 c5 ea 69 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 44 d4 62 c5 ea 7f 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d6 5c c4 ea b9 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d4 5c c4 ea 95 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d5 65 c7 e2 b6 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d6 61 c6 e4 6f 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d4 61 c6 e4 43 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d6 61 c5 e6 b3 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d5 61 c5 e6 89 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d4 61 c5 e6 9f 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d6 61 c4 dd c7 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d4 61 c4 dd eb 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 55 d5 65 c7 d3 aa 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 55 d4 65 c7 d3 bc 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d6 61 c6 da 5e 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 d5 61 c6 da 64 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 44 d5 61 c5 ec 34 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d6 60 c4 e9 59 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 42 d4 60 c4 e9 75 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 41 d6 62 c6 d6 be 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 41 d5 62 c6 d6 84 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d6 61 c5 d9 fc 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 44 d4 61 c5 d9 d0 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d6 60 c3 de 3c 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d5 60 c3 de 06 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 42 d4 60 c3 de 10 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 41 d6 61 c6 e2 04 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 44 d5 61 c5 df 5f 80
00 00 1d e0 ed a5 44 d4 61 c5 df 49 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d6 5f c4 d8 9a 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d5 5f c4 d8 a0 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 42 d4 5f c4 d8 b6 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 55 d6 65 c7 d8 53 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 55 d4 65 c7 d8 7f 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d6 61 c6 dc c7 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d5 61 c6 dc fd 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 41 d4 61 c6 dc eb 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d6 61 c5 df 1c 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d5 61 c5 df 26 80
00 00 1c e0 ed a5 44 d4 61 c5 df 30 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d5 60 c3 e6 5c 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 42 d4 60 c3 e6 4a 80
00 00 1e e0 ed a5 55 d5 65 c7 e6 aa 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 de 61 c6 f7 2d 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 dd 61 c6 f7 17 80
00 00 1f e0 ed a5 41 dc 61 c6 f7 01 80
```

**EDIT:** The question is how to decode temperature & pressure from the received data.

Comment: For completeness: this question was asked again with more details and some comments: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/11539/2781